# medical notes dataset

Tags: medical

I am working on a project title chronic disease prediction using Artificial Intelligence. I am looking for medical notes data. if anyone have access please provide it. I have seen some links on keggle but they are not providing access. I need data as some patients go to hospital/doctor and said I am having following symptoms/allergy/I have been to these operation/I am alcohol consumer like and the result should be found he/she is suffering from x of disease. If anyone has any data like this please share.

Comment: Sorry, this is too little information - *medical notes* can be anything. Please read [What a good request looks like](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like) and [edit] your question.

Comment: If anyone has a collection of such data, it is probably under Nondisclosure Agreement. You can check http://topos.averbis.de/publikationen/ . - This is a research project , Deep learning combined with Text Mining for studying imagery of eyesight diseases. They combine Deep Learning of image data with information from doctors' letters which might contain valuable phrases such as "therapy was successful" etc. Letters are in German and of course they are not publicly available. (I saw a talk about this study)

Answer (score 1):

[MIMIC-III](https://physionet.org/physiobank/database/mimic3cdb/) is a possible dataset to look at.